# Replace question mark in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

When reading dataframes from a source like a csv file, literals like '?' are shown for blank values in pandas.
[image]

If this is a numerical column and you try replacing with mean like `df['weight'].replace('?',df['weight'].mean() ,inplace='True')` may not work if it is of type 'Object' and not int64.

In such cases I replace these '?' with NaN because isna() does not work on them directly. Then these NaNs are replaced with 0s and finally use them to replace with the actual values to impute

```
df['SGOT'].replace('?',np.nan,inplace='True' )
df1['SGOT'].fillna(value=0,inplace=True)

df1['SGOT']=df1['SGOT'].astype(int)
df1['SGOT'].replace(0,df1['SGOT'].mean(),inplace=True )
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this. Please let me know

Comment: Did you try pandas `Series.str.replace` ?

Comment: Try `df["SGOT"].apply(lambda x:  df[df["SGOT"]!="?"]["SGOT"].astype("int").mean() if x=="?" else x)`  if you want to calculate mean with the denominator as number of rows  excluding the "?" rows. If you want to consider all the rows to calculate mean, then try `df["SGOT"].apply(lambda x:  df["SGOT"].str.replace("?",0).astype("int").mean() if x=="?" else x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you read the data (presumably with `pd.read_csv()`) is a good time to replace `'?'` by `nan`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., na_values='?')
```

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). `na_values` can be also be a list or a dict.

By default, this will *add* `'?'` to the list of strings that are to be interpreted as NaN (you can change that with `keep_default_na=False` if you prefer).

Comment: thanks @Pierre this seems like a good solution to get around the datatype issue as well

Answer (score 1):

You can send a dict as argument to `df.replace()` where this dict will include the columns names with the values to replace and the new ones. And for the mean value for a column you can specify the argument `errors` as `True`. Here is a code to explain :

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'BILIRUBIN': [1, '?', 1, 0.4, 0.7], 
                   'SGOT':[18, '?','?',18, 18], 
                   'ALK_PHOSPHATE':[85, '?', '?', 45, 71]})

replace_dict = {'SGOT': {'?': pd.to_numeric(df.SGOT, errors='coerce').mean()}, 
                'BILIRUBIN':{'?': pd.to_numeric(df.BILIRUBIN, errors='coerce').mean()}, 
                'ALK_PHOSPHATE':{'?': pd.to_numeric(df.ALK_PHOSPHATE, errors='coerce').mean()}}

df.replace(replace_dict, inplace=True)

>>> df
   BILIRUBIN  SGOT  ALK_PHOSPHATE
0      1.000  18.0           85.0
1      0.775  18.0           67.0
2      1.000  18.0           67.0
3      0.400  18.0           45.0
4      0.700  18.0           71.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your dataframe actually. If you have multiple datatypes in your dataframe (say string and integers) then replace function won't work even after using inplace = True. In that case you can use

```
# Replace "?" with np.nan in string columns
df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, str) and x.strip() == "?" else x)

# Replace "?" with np.nan in integer columns
df.replace("?", np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Hope this helps.